# jenkins, kubernetes and minikube

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to run integrate minikube with jenkins. I get the following exception:

[image]

when I run kubectl get pods
NAME                         READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-slave-1d0d94d95d22   1/2       Completed   0          32s
jenkins-slave-1d0fe45cdf1d   1/2       Completed   0          22s
jenkins-slave-1d123866bd8f   1/2       Completed   0          12s
jenkins-slave-1d148c8ccd15   1/2       Completed   0          2s

kubectl logs jenkins-slave-1d0d94d95d22
Error from server: a container name must be specified for pod jenkins-slave-1d0d94d95d22, choose one of: [jnlp kubecrt]

The configuration is as given in the following 
Kubernetes url :192.168.99.101:8443
[Kubernetes 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAYr7.png)

Would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: it contains all steps to use dynamic slaves on minikube https://medium.com/@lvthillo/deploy-jenkins-with-dynamic-slaves-in-minikube-8aef5404e9c1

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that your jenkins slave doesn't connect to jenkins master.

Maybe clicking the `Launch` on your jenkins slave machine solves your problem.

1. Open up a browser on your jenkins slave
2. Type the URL of jenkins service (probably `http://192.168.XXX.XXX:8080/computer`).
3. Go to the `Launch` button page.
4. Click the button.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now I get the error as given below  Agent jenkins-slave-241c54433a80 (jenkins-slave)

This agent is offline because Jenkins failed to launch the agent process on it. See log for more details

slaveAgentPort.disabled Go to security configuration screen and change it.
Labels

kub
Projects tied to jenkins-slave-241c54433a80

None    When I try to open logs  the logs are empty.